# Cannot serve static site in Apache using Docker

Tags: php, docker, apache2

I cannot serve static PHP site in Apache. I mean only text of the php site is visible but no css and js are present (even in the browser console). All this is in docker:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY deploy/apache/default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2 -y
RUN apt install -y apache2 \
  php5.6 \
  php5.6-fpm \
  php5.6-dom \
  php5.6-cgi \
  libapache2-mod-php5.6 \
  libapache2-mod-fcgid \
  software-properties-common

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ./deploy/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Entrypoint:

```
apachectl -D FOREGROUND

exec "$@"
```

Php file is:

```
<? include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/site.php";
   include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/inc/functions.php";
topp();

?>
    <div id="gallerywrapper">
        <div id="gallery">
            <div id="imagearea">
                <div id="image">
                    <a href="javascript:slideShow.nav(-1)" class="imgnav " id="previmg"></a>

                    <a href="javascript:slideShow.nav(1)" class="imgnav " id="nextimg"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="thumbwrapper">
                <div id="thumbarea">
                    <ul id="thumbs">
                    <!--
                        <li id="bad1"><img src="/img/forsidebilder_stor/thumbs/bad1.jpg" width="147" height="64" alt="" /></li>
                       -->
                        <? echo create_slideshow("forside"); ?>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="leftcolumn" style="margin-top:5px;">
                <div style="padding:5px;">
                    <h3>ONLY THING I SEE</h3>
                </div>


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var imgid = 'image';
var imgdir = 'img/photos/JPEG';
var imgext = '.jpg';
var thumbid = 'thumbs';
var auto = true;
var autodelay = 8;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/slideshow.js"></script>

<? bunn(); ?>
```

I clearly missing something.

[edit]
I guess it is connected to:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/site.php";
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/inc/functions.php";
```

When I'm pasting content of site.php it is showing images and css.

Comment: Dont you think that as you are using Docker, that would have been a relevant Tag to add to the question and probably the Title

Comment: How are you starting the Docker container? Are you passing a port to connect to Apache? 